# Difference ways of implementing methods

Tags: java

I'm starting coding and I find this question about implementing methods from another project.

For example in this code I can use the methods I use in CreateECASPageObject in my project CreateECAsDefinitions, but I know if I use extends in this class , I also can use the methods. I am confused.

I can use the method like this:
IngresarECAs.FirstMethod() in the project below;

Are they the same using extends and the way I am using?

```java
public class CreateECAsDefinitions {

    private LectorExcel excel;
    private static  XSSFSheet hoja;
    private int fila;

      @Before
        public void before(Scenario scenario) {
            this.scenarioActual = scenario;
        }


      @Steps  
      private CreateECAsPageObject IngresarECAs ;
      private ValidacionCasosPageObject validacionCasos;
```

I want to know what the difference if I put:

```
private CreateECASPageObject IngresarECAs;
```

or put this:

```
public class CreateECAsDefinitions extends CreateECASPageObject
```

At the beginning.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a difference of implementing methods. This is the difference between [*composition* and *inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

If you do not need or want `CreateECAsDefinitions` or *inherit* all accessible fields and methods of `CreateECASPageObject`, then you should not use `extends`. In other words, you are hiding away functionality of the possible parent class by "composing" rather than "inheriting".

Given that you have not shown the method definition, it is hard to say what way should be preferred given your scenario, but if find yourself writing this pattern for each and every method within `CreateECAsPageObject` class, then you might want to then use inheritance.

```
private CreateECAsPageObject ingresarECAs ;

public void firstMethod() {
    ingresarECAs.firstMethod();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I am confused because I can access to the methods of the class "CreateECAsPageObject" withouth use extends , so I am not sure if I put this private CreateECAsPageObject ingresarECAs , it is almost the same as using extends.

Comment: You need to use the instance of `ingresarECAs` to use it's public methods, yes. It is not the same as using extends because you are not required to override or expose all of its methods.

Answer (score 0):

You ask the difference between inheritance and composition. It is a broad subject.
Inheritance (`extends` keyword) and composition (`private` instance field in the class) are two distinct approaches to set a dependency between two classes.
The general idiom is favor composition over inheritance because composition is more flexible in terms of possibility (for example you can compose with multiple fields but inheriting a single class) and reduces the coupling between the two classes. But in some cases, inheritance may make sense to reduce boiler plate code (repetitive code) or verbosity.

In your case with inheritance you write `firstMethod()` and with composition you have to write `ingresarECAs.firstMethod()`.   In such a simple case, hard to spot a great design advantage in the first or the second way.
But defining a base test class may make sense in some case to force other test classes to rely on the same logic.
So definitively I think that you should probably think about your requirements and set the cursor between inheritance and composition at the right place according to them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I am confused because I can access to the methods of the class "CreateECAsPageObject" withouth use extends , so I am not sure if I put this private CreateECAsPageObject ingresarECAs , it is almost the same as using extends.